# How to use for-loops and if-else statements to iteratively run a software on command line

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

For all the `.mcool files`, I extract the `id`, which is the string before the `.mcool` extension.
If the substring of `id` after the last `/` is either 5000, 10000, or 50000 (i.e., 5k, 10k, or 50k), I want to run `predictSV` from [EagleC](https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC#overview-of-the-commands).

For a single `.mcool` file, as per described on [EagleC](https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC#overview-of-the-commands), it would be:

```
    cooler ls SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool

    predictSV --hic-5k SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool::/resolutions/5000 \
                --hic-10k SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool::/resolutions/10000 \
                --hic-50k SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool::/resolutions/50000 \
                -O SK-N-AS -g hg38 --balance-type CNV --output-format full \
                --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999
```

However, now I want to run EagleC iteratively for multiple `.mcool` files.

```
for id in cooler ls ./input/*.mcool; do
  if  [ "${id##*/}" = 5000 ] || [ "${id##*/}" = 10000 ] || [ "${id##*/}" = 50000 ]; then 
    for num in ${id##*/:0:1}; do         
      predictSV --hic-"${num}"k "${id##*/}" -g hg38 --balance-type CNV --output-format full \
--prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999; 
    done;
  fi;
done
```

My code exits without returning any output.

The following code

```
for id in cooler ls ./input/*.mcool; do echo "$id"; done
```

returns:

```
 cooler
ls
./input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A001C008.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A001C011.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A001C013.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A001C019.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A001C023.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A001C024.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C001.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C002.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C006.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C010.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C012.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C013.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C122.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A002C212.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C004.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C012.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C038.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C040.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C041.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C045.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C046.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C053.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A014C054.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A015C004.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A015C006.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/A015C010.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/combined.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/CRC15157.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/CRC19779.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/CRC25135.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/CRC25988.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/CRC26616.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./input/CRC8396.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
(EagleC)
```

Comment: please update the question with: *a)* complete output from `for id in cooler ls ./input/*.mcool; do echo "$ls"; done` and *b)* the expected output; alternatively, add the `echo "$ls"` after the 1st `do` and before the `if`, and add `echo "$num"` after the 2nd `do` and before the `predictSV` call .... with the objective being to verify these variarables (`ls`, `num`) contain what you think they contain

Comment: `for id in cooler ls ./input/*.mcool; do echo "$ls"; done` returns nothing

Comment: Is `cooler` or `./input` the source files directory?

Comment: Cooler is a command from EagleC (https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC#overview-of-the-commands)

Comment: Assuming the cooler command is `cooler ls ./input/*.mcool`, try changing your loop to `while read -r id ; do echo "id" ; done < <(cooler ls ./input/*.mcool)`. You can utilize bash process substitution to read the output from the `cooler` command.

Comment: @j_b it returns an error. I edited the question to display the error.

Comment: Does the `cooler ls ./input/*.mcool` command return the same error when executed by itself?

Comment: @j_b yes, `cooler ls ./input/*.mcool` returns the same error but no error when I execute it for one file at a time e.g., `cooler ls ./input/A001C008.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool`.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my behalf, try: `for id in cooler ls ./input/*.mcool; do echo "$id"; done` (replace `$ls` with `$id`)

Comment: @markp-fuso added the output

Comment: @markp-fuso The output for `cooler ls {.mcool}` lists the files in various dimensions, as shown in the `cooler ls SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool` line on the github page (https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC#overview-of-the-commands). The substring after the last "/" is what I'm looking for.

Comment: ahhhh, silly me ... the current code ... `for id in cooler ls ./input/*.mcool` actually *is* doing what's coded ... the `./input/*.mcool` is expanded to a list of files that match this pattern, then the `for` loop processes each value assigned to `id` .... `id = 'cooler'` ... `id = 'ls'` ... `id = 1st_file_in_file_list` ... `id = 2nd_file_in_file_list` ... etc; @j_b's recommendation (`while read ... done < <(cooler ls ...)`) is the correct 'fix', but if that's generating an error then it sounds like a bad/invalid `cooler` call

Comment: My current code is `for mcool_file in ./input/*.mcool; do
        while IFS= read -r id; do
        if  [ "${id##*/}" = 5000 ] || [ "${id##*/}" = 10000 ] || [ "${id##*/}" = 50000 ]; then 
                for num in ${id##*/:0:1}; do         
                predictSV --hic-"${num}"k "${id##*/}" -g hg38 --balance-type CNV --output-format full \
                --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999; 
                done;
        fi; 
        done < <(cooler ls "$mcool_file")
done`. Should specify `--hic-"${num}"k "${id##*/}"` for each resolution?

Comment: Please do not keep on asking the same question and deleting the old versions. Instead you should improve the existing question by using the [edit] facility (see below the question).

Comment: Please do not add lots of unformatted code in comments, it is unreadable. Instead you should [edit] the question to show the extra details. Perhaps you could review the [tour] and the [help] pages to remind yourself of the rules of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to iterate over files before you iterate over lines of output from running `cooler ls` against those files.

```bash
for mcool_file in ./input/*.mcool; do
  while IFS= read -r id; do
    id_suffix=${id##*/}
    case $id_suffix in 5000|10000|50000)
      num=${id_suffix:0:1}
      predictSV \
        --hic-"${num}k" "$id_suffix" \
        -g hg38 \
        --balance-type CNV \
        --output-format full \
        --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 \
        --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 \
        --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999
      ;;
    esac
  done < <(cooler ls "$mcool_file")
done
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I fit in the remaining code `; do
  if  [ "${id##*/}" = 5000 ] || [ "${id##*/}" = 10000 ] || [ "${id##*/}" = 50000 ]; then 
    for num in ${id##*/:0:1}; do         
      predictSV --hic-"${num}"k "${id##*/}" -g hg38 --balance-type CNV --output-format full \
--prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999; 
    done;
  fi;
done`? Should it be after the first `done`?

Comment: @melolili It should go where the `echo` is. I thought the text I was echoing made that clear.

Comment: @melolili, taking a closer look, btw, the inner `for` loop was useless; `${id##*/:0:1}` only evaluates to exactly one value, so it's not going to be doing any actual looping; might as well just make the code a simple assignment. I've edited to demonstrate.

Comment: Based on the github documentation (https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC#overview-of-the-commands), would the code be able to iteratively run `--hic-5k`, `--hic-10k`, and `--hic-50k` for the files with substring 5000, 10000, and 50000, respectively?

Comment: @melolili, of course, you can add an inner loop for that. But this has already gone beyond the scope of the question you asked; if you have a distinct problem doing that yourself, you should ask a question about that problem separately.

Comment: Ok that helps! One last thing...if I want to set the -O parameter as the substring of `id` before the first occurence of `.`, would `id_name=${id%%.*}` be accurate?

Comment: Yes, `${id%%.*}` will indeed remove everything after the first `.` in `id`.